# Trying to create function to extract slice between special characters

Tags: python, string, function, slice

I have code that I thought would work, but it does not. In particular, how can I handle the case where there is only a begin or end phrase within the text. See my code below. Thanks!

```py
import re
def extract(text, begin, end):
   result1 = re.search(begin, text)
   if result1 is None:
      index1 = " "
   else:
      index1 = text.find(begin) + len(begin)
   result2 = re.search(end, text)
   if result2 is None:
      index2 = " "
   else:
      index2 = text.find(end)
   return text[index1:index2]

print(extract("Eat an <apple> each day", "<", ">"))

print(extract("Oh [/b] no", "[b]", "[/b]"))
```

#First case works as expected and prints "apple". I am expecting "Oh" to print for the second case, but it's not returning anything. Why not and how do I fix it?
[image][image]

Answer (score 1):

You really don't need to use regex here. In fact, your problem in part is *due* to the fact that you use regex. `[` and `]` are special characters in regex, and it essentially means "match any single character that is listed" between the two brackets. So your string will try to match a `b` for begin and either `/` or `b` for end. We can do this without using regex using just the `.find` method, which will actually return `-1` if it couldn't find anyting.

```py
def extract(text, begin, end):
    index1 = text.find(begin)
    if index1 != -1:
        index1 += len(begin)
    # start next search at index1, or 0 if begin not found
    index2 = text.find(end, index1 if index1 != -1 else 0)
    print(index1, index2)
    if index2 != -1:
        # end string found!
        return text[index1 if index1 != -1 else 0:index2]
    elif index1 != -1:
        # begin string found!
        return text[index1:index2  if index2 != -1 else len(text)]

print(extract("Eat an <apple> each day", "<", ">"))
# "apple"
print(extract("Oh [/b] no", "[b]", "[/b]"))
# "Oh "
print(extract("Oh [b] no", "[b]", "[/b]"))
# " no"
```

Comment: Excellent. My code not working due to the brackets being special characters in regex makes perfect sense. But if I use indexing only, I am running into the same issue:

Comment: import re
def extract(text, begin, end):
   index1 = text.find(begin) + len(begin)
   index2 = text.find(end)
   return text[index1:index2]

print(extract("Eat an <apple> each day", "<", ">"))

print(extract("Oh [/b] no", "[b]", "[/b]"))

#First case works as expected and prints "apple". I am still not getting "Oh" as desired for the second example.

Comment: Sorry, I am submitting from my phone and the code is coming out garbled.

Comment: I did not see your code at first. Thank you. I believe this will work.

Answer (score 0):

uses indexing

```
s = "abcacbAUG[GAC]UGAfjdalfd"
start = s.find("[") + len("[")
end = s.find("]")
substring = s[start:end]
print(substring)
```

prints GAC

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But what if start is not present in the string? Also, this code does not make use of a function and variables.

Comment: Also, I am most curious about why my code doesn't do what I think it should.

Comment: what do you mean by start is not present in the string? start is just a character or string which is the left side of the string you are interested in and end is the right side. let me edit the code to be more obvious

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is your second regexp. `[b]` and `[/b]` does different thing than you think:

- `[b]` chooses **single character `b`**
- `[/b]` chooses **single character `b` or single character `/`**

You have to **escape the square brackets** if you want to match `[/b]` in the text.

I also modified the index evaluation. Since you already `search`ed the string and have result, you can use `result.span()` to get the indices (start-end as a `tuple`) of the match.

```py
import re
def extract(text, begin, end):
   result1 = re.search(begin, text)
   if result1 is None:
      index1 = 0
   else:
      index1 = result1.span()[1]
   result2 = re.search(end, text)
   if result2 is None:
      index2 = len(text)
   else:
      index2 = result2.span()[0]
   return text[index1:index2]

print(extract("Eat an <apple> each day", "<", ">"))
print(extract("Oh [/b] no", r"\[b\]", r"\[/b\]"))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use regex, you can look for:

- optionally (but if possible) as many characters as possible followed by the begin sequence (non-capturing group)
- then the characters you want to capture (any number of any non-newline character, although as few as possible)
- then the end sequence or end of line (another non-capturing group)

You need to escape the sequences (see use of `re.escape`), and not doing so may be part of your current problem, e.g. the `[b]` is treated as a character class.

```
def extract(text, begin, end):

    begin = re.escape(begin)
    end = re.escape(end)

    reg = f'(?:.*{begin})?(.*?)(?:{end}|$)'
    match = re.match(reg, text)
    if match:
        return match.group(1)
```